# How to compare values between key value pairs in a dictionary of python?

Tags: python, dictionary

My plan is to take every value in a python dict, so I have done that.

```
data = {}
for _ in range(int(input())):
    n = input()
    s = float(input())
    data.update({n: s})


>>> 2
>>> harry
>>> 2
>>> barry
>>> 3
>>> {'harry': 2.0, 'barry': 3.0}
```

now I want to compare the **VALUES** in this dict and return the result of max-min. How could i do this ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the values of a dict with [`data.values()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values). That gives you a perfectly good iterable that you can pass to [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) or [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min):

```
>>> data = {'harry': 2.0, 'barry': 3.0}
>>> max(data.values())
3.0
```

---

Or you can get the key-value pairs with [`data.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items), and pass the result to `max` or `min` with a [`key` function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) that compares on the second part of the pair instead of the first:

```
>>> max(data.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1])
('barry', 3.0)
```

Or, instead of writing the `key` function manually, you can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to do it for you:

```
>>> max(data.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
('barry', 3.0)
```

---

Or you can get the keys (either with [`data.keys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get), or just using `data` itself as the iterable—dictionaries are iterables of their keys), and use the dict's [`data.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method as your key function:

```
>>> max(data, key=data.get)
'barry'
```

---

Or, if you need to do a lot of these value-based searches, you might want to create a reverse dictionary:

```
>>> revdata = {value: key for key, value in data.items()}
>>> max(revdata)
3.0
>>> max(revdata.items())
(3.0, 'barry')
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want just the values:

```
min_value = min(data.values())
max_value = max(data.values())
```

If you want the key (getting the value later is easy):

```
min_key = min(data, key=data.get)  # key=data.__getitem__ will also work
max_key = max(data, key=data.get)
```